# Error building a Checkers Game

Tags: java, arrays

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at neegjar.Play.canJump(Play.java:113)
at neegjar.Play.getLegalMoves(Play.java:278)
at neegjar.Board.printLegalMoves(Board.java:198)
at neegjar.main.main(main.java:17)
Java Result: 1
```

I am trying to build a checkers Game in java (in the console for now). I have 6 classes:

- Board: displays and keeps track of the board. It is a 2d array of Square objects called mySquare.
- CheckerMove: contains variables fromX, fromY, toX, toY and boolean isAJump. In Play, I create an Array of CheckerMove objects to find out what moves are valid.
- Piece: A single checker piece. Each player has an array of 12 Piece objects to use. Contains variables xCoord, yCoord, isKing, isAlive and team.
- Play: Basically the backbone of the project. Handles what is considered a valid move, what is a "jump", etc. It is included below.
- Square: A square object is a single tile on the checkers board. It contains variables squareColor, hasAPiece, and hasARedPiece( player one).
- main (contains main method)

When I try to run the main method which creates the board, places the pieces, and prints the legal moves, everything works until it tries to print the legal moves (it displays the error message above).

Why is it doing this? I have no idea. I would appreciate any help, and thank you for taking the time to read this!

Here is Play:

```
package neegjar;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Play extends Board
{

public int currentPlayer;
public boolean gameOver;
public int turnNumber;



public Play()
{
    currentPlayer = 1;
    gameOver = false;
    turnNumber = 0;



}

public void takeTurn()
{
    System.out.println("It is player "+ this.currentPlayer + "'s         turn");         
//for Player 1
    have user select a piece
    System.out.println("Select a piece by typing and x coordinate,              followed by a y coordinate (seperated by commas");
    System.out.println("For an example input, type h");

}

//can the piece jump from x1,y1 TO x2,y2?
public boolean canJump(int player, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
{
    boolean CURRENT_KING = false;  //by default
    int CURRENT_PIECE = -1;

    if(player == 1)
    {
        if((x2 != x1+2) && (x2 != x1-2) && (y2 != y1+2) && (y2 != y1-2))   return false;


        for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            if((player1Pieces[i].getX() == x1)&&(player1Pieces[i].getY() == y1))
            {
                CURRENT_PIECE = i;
                break;  //get out of foor loop
            }                    
        }                
        if(player1Pieces[CURRENT_PIECE].isAKing() == true)
        {
            CURRENT_KING = true;    

        }

        //top left spot
        if((x2 == x1-2)&&(y2 == y1-2))
        {
            //first check to see if there is an enemy black piece on the adjacent square
            if((mySquare[y1-1][x1-1].getHasAPiece()==true)&&(mySquare[y1-1][x1-1].getHasARedPiece()==false))
                if((mySquare[y1-2][x1-2].getHasAPiece()==true)||(y1-2 < 0)||(x1-2 < 0)) //check for a blocker
                {    
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    return true;
        }

        //top right spot
        if((x2 == x1+2)&&(y2 == y1-2))
        {   
            //first check to see if there is an enemy black piece on the adjacent square
            if((mySquare[y1-1][x1+1].getHasAPiece()==true)&&(mySquare[y1-1][x1+1].getHasARedPiece()==false))
                if((mySquare[y1-2][x1+2].getHasAPiece()==true)||(y1-2 < 0)||(x1+2 > 7)) //check for a blocker
                {    
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    return true;
        }

        //Next 2 are for Kings only!
        if(CURRENT_KING = true)
        {
            //bottom left
            if((x2 == x1-2)&&(y2 == y1+2))    
            {
                if((mySquare[y1+1][x1-1].getHasAPiece()==true)&&(mySquare[y1+1][x1-1].getHasARedPiece()==false))
                    if((mySquare[y1+2][x1-2].getHasAPiece()==true)||(y1+2 > 7)||(x1-2 < 0)) //check for a blocker or out of bounds
                    {    
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                        return true;    

            }

            //bottom right
            if((x2 == x1+2)&&(y2 == y1+2))
            {
                if((mySquare[y1+1][x1+1].getHasAPiece()==true)&&(mySquare[y1+1][x1+1].getHasARedPiece()==false))
                    if((mySquare[y1+2][x1+2].getHasAPiece()==true)||(y1+2 > 7)||(x1+2 >7)) //check for a blocker
                    {    
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                        return true;     
            }


        }//end if King

    }//end p1


    if(player == 2)
    {
        if((x2 != x1+2) && (x2 != x1-2) && (y2 != y1+2) && (y2 != y1-2))   return false;

        for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            if((player2Pieces[i].getX() == x1)&&(player2Pieces[i].getY() == y1))
            {
                CURRENT_PIECE = i;
                break;  //get out of foor loop
            }                    
        }                
        if(player2Pieces[CURRENT_PIECE].isAKing() == true)
        {
            CURRENT_KING = true;    

        }

        //bottom left
        if((x2 == x1-2)&&(y2 == y1+2))    
        {
            if((mySquare[y1+1][x1-1].getHasAPiece()==true)&&(mySquare[y1+1][x1-1].getHasARedPiece()==false))
                if((mySquare[y1+2][x1-2].getHasAPiece()==true)||(y1+2 > 7)||(x1-2 < 0)) //check for a blocker or out of bounds
                {    
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    return true;    

        }

        //bottom right
        if((x2 == x1+2)&&(y2 == y1+2))
        {
            if((mySquare[y1+1][x1+1].getHasAPiece()==true)&&(mySquare[y1+1][x1+1].getHasARedPiece()==false))
                if((mySquare[y1+2][x1+2].getHasAPiece()==true)||(y1+2 > 7)||(x1+2 >7)) //check for a blocker
                {    
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    return true;     
        }

        //Next 2 are for Kings only!
        if(CURRENT_KING = true)
        {
            //top left spot
            if((x2 == x1-2)&&(y2 == y1-2))
            {
                //first check to see if there is an enemy black piece on the adjacent square
                if((mySquare[y1-1][x1-1].getHasAPiece()==true)&&(mySquare[y1-1][x1-1].getHasARedPiece()==false))
                    if((mySquare[y1-2][x1-2].getHasAPiece()==true)||(y1-2 < 0)||(x1-2 < 0)) //check for a blocker
                    {    
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                        return true;
            }

            //top right spot
            if((x2 == x1+2)&&(y2 == y1-2))
            {   
                //first check to see if there is an enemy black piece on the adjacent square
                if((mySquare[y1-1][x1+1].getHasAPiece()==true)&&(mySquare[y1-1][x1+1].getHasARedPiece()==false))
                    if((mySquare[y1-2][x1+2].getHasAPiece()==true)||(y1-2 < 0)||(x1+2 > 7)) //check for a blocker
                    {    
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                        return true;
            }     

            }//end if king
    } //end p2

    //default, or if nothing is found
    return false;


}  // end canJump()

/**
   * This is called by the getLegalMoves() method to determine whether
   * the player can legally move from (r1,c1) to (r2,c2).  It is
   * assumed that (r1,r2) contains one of the player's pieces and
   * that (r2,c2) is a neighboring square.
   */
public boolean canMove(int player, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
{

   if (y2 < 0 || y2 >= 8 || x2 < 0 || x2 >= 8)  //check to see if move is on the board
      return false;

   if (mySquare[y2][x2].getHasAPiece() == true)
      return false;  // (r2,c2) already contains a piece.

   if (player == 1) 
   {
      if (mySquare[y1][x1].getHasARedPiece() == true && y2 < y1)
         return false;  //red can only move up if not a king
      return true; 
   }
   else     //player == 2
   {
      if (mySquare[y1][x1].getHasAPiece() == true && mySquare[y1][x1].getHasARedPiece()==false && y2 > y1)
         return false;  // black can only move down if not a king
      return true;  
   }

}  // end canMove()

public CheckerMove[] getLegalMoves(int whichPlayer)
{
    int pX =0;
    int pY = 0;
    int CURRENT_PIECE = -1;    //used to signify desired piece
    boolean CURRENT_KING = false;   //default not a king
    ArrayList<CheckerMove> legalMoves = new ArrayList<CheckerMove>();  //ADJUSTABLE arraylist of legalMoves
    if((whichPlayer != 1)&&(whichPlayer != 2)) return null; //not a valid player


//player One /********************************************************/
    if(whichPlayer == 1)
    {
        //loop through array to find piece
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            if(player1Pieces[i].getIsAlive() == false) break;
            if(player1Pieces[i].isAKing() == true)
                CURRENT_KING = true;

            pX = player1Pieces[i].getX();
            pY = player1Pieces[i].getY();

            //check for Jumps 1st
                if (canJump(1, pX, pY, pX+2, pY+2))
                    legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(pX, pY, pX+2, pY+2, true));
                if (canJump(1, pX, pY, pX-2, pY+2))
                    legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(pX, pY, pX-2, pY+2, true));
                if (canJump(1, pX, pY, pX+2, pY-2))
                    legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(pX, pY, pX+2, pY-2, true));
                if (canJump(1, pX, pY, pX-2, pY-2))
                    legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(pX, pY, pX-2, pY-2, true));


        }//end for

        if (legalMoves.size() == 0) //if there are no jumps
        {
            //loop through pieces array to find valid moves for each piece
            for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 12; ctr++)
            {
                if(player1Pieces[ctr].isAlive == true)
                {
                    int currX = player1Pieces[ctr].getX();
                    int currY = player1Pieces[ctr].getY();
                    if(canMove(1,currX,currY,currX-1,currY-1))
                        legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(currX,currY,currX-1,currY-1,false));
                    if(canMove(1,currX,currY,currX+1,currY-1))
                        legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(currX,currY,currX+1,currY-1,false));
                    if(canMove(1,currX,currY,currX-1,currY+1))
                        legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(currX,currY,currX-1,currY+1,false));
                    if(canMove(1,currX,currY,currX+1,currY+1))
                        legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(currX,currY,currX+1,currY+1,false));

                }
            }

        }//if no legal moves exist


    }//end player One /**********************************************/
//player Two
    if(whichPlayer == 2)
    {
        //loop through array to find piece
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {

            if(player2Pieces[i].getIsAlive() == false) break;

            if(player2Pieces[i].isAKing() == true)
                CURRENT_KING = true;

            pX = player2Pieces[i].getX();
            pY = player2Pieces[i].getY();

            //check for Jumps 1st
                if (canJump(2, pX, pY, pX+2, pY+2))
                    legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(pX, pY, pX+2, pY+2, true));
                if (canJump(2, pX, pY, pX-2, pY+2))
                   legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(pX, pY, pX-2, pY+2, true));
                if (canJump(2, pX, pY, pX+2, pY-2))
                   legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(pX, pY, pX+2, pY-2, true));
                if (canJump(2, pX, pY, pX-2, pY-2))
                   legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(pX, pY, pX-2, pY-2, true));
        }//end for

        if (legalMoves.size() == 0) //if there are no jumps
        {
            //loop through pieces array to find valid moves for each piece
            for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 12; ctr++)
            {
                if(player2Pieces[ctr].isAlive == true)
                {
                    int currX = player2Pieces[ctr].getX();
                    int currY = player2Pieces[ctr].getY();
                    if(canMove(2,currX,currY,currX-1,currY-1))
                        legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(currX,currY,currX-1,currY-1,false));
                    if(canMove(2,currX,currY,currX+1,currY-1))
                        legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(currX,currY,currX+1,currY-1,false));
                    if(canMove(2,currX,currY,currX-1,currY+1))
                        legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(currX,currY,currX-1,currY+1,false));
                    if(canMove(2,currX,currY,currX+1,currY+1))
                        legalMoves.add(new CheckerMove(currX,currY,currX+1,currY+1,false));

                }
            }

        }

    }//end p2

    if (legalMoves.size() == 0)
        return null;    //no legal moves found
    else    //there are legal moves, so copy array list to an array and return
    {
        CheckerMove[] validMoves = new CheckerMove[legalMoves.size()];
        for (int lastCtr = 0; lastCtr < legalMoves.size(); lastCtr++)
        {
            validMoves[lastCtr] = legalMoves.get(lastCtr);
        }
        return validMoves;
    }

}//end getLegalMoves




}//end class
```

Here is Board:

```
package neegjar;




public class Board
{
public Square mySquare[][] = new Square[8][8];
public boolean gameover;

//initialize an Array of 12 Pieces (for the checkers) for EACH player 
public Piece player1Pieces[] = new Piece[12];; //declaration
public Piece player2Pieces[] = new Piece[12]; //declaration

public Board()
{
//CREATE THE BOARd  
//mySquare = new Square[8][8];
//initialize mySquare 
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) //not sure if I need this
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        mySquare[i][j] = new Square();
    }
} 
//initialize player1 and 2 Pieces arrays
initPieces(1);
initPieces(2);


//alternating colors  
/*
for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
{
  for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
  {

    if ((row == 0) || (row % 2 == 0) && ((col == 0) || (col % 2 == 0)))
    {
      mySquare[row][col].squareColor = "white";
    }
    else
    {
      // do nothing, the square will be black by default
    }
  }
}//end for loop
*/

//

}//end constructor 

public void placePieces()
{  
//set location of the pieces' initial location
//player 1    
player1Pieces[0].move(0,5); 
    mySquare[5][0].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[5][0].setHasARedPiece(true);
player1Pieces[1].move(2,5);
    mySquare[5][2].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[5][2].setHasARedPiece(true);
player1Pieces[2].move(4,5);
    mySquare[5][4].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[5][4].setHasARedPiece(true);
player1Pieces[3].move(6,5);
    mySquare[5][6].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[5][6].setHasARedPiece(true);

player1Pieces[4].move(1,6);
    mySquare[6][1].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[6][1].setHasARedPiece(true);
player1Pieces[5].move(3,6);
    mySquare[6][3].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[6][3].setHasARedPiece(true);
player1Pieces[6].move(5,6);
    mySquare[6][5].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[6][5].setHasARedPiece(true);
player1Pieces[7].move(7,6);
    mySquare[6][7].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[6][7].setHasARedPiece(true);

player1Pieces[8].move(0,7);
    mySquare[7][0].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[7][0].setHasARedPiece(true);
player1Pieces[9].move(2,7);
    mySquare[7][2].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[7][2].setHasARedPiece(true);
player1Pieces[10].move(4,7);
    mySquare[7][4].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[7][4].setHasARedPiece(true);
player1Pieces[11].move(6,7);
    mySquare[7][6].setHasAPiece(true);
    mySquare[7][6].setHasARedPiece(true);
//player 2
player2Pieces[0].move(1,0);
    mySquare[0][1].setHasAPiece(true);
player2Pieces[1].move(3,0);
    mySquare[0][3].setHasAPiece(true);
player2Pieces[2].move(5,0);
    mySquare[0][5].setHasAPiece(true);
player2Pieces[3].move(7,0);
    mySquare[0][7].setHasAPiece(true);

player2Pieces[4].move(0,1);
    mySquare[1][0].setHasAPiece(true);
player2Pieces[5].move(2,1);
    mySquare[1][2].setHasAPiece(true);
player2Pieces[6].move(4,1);
    mySquare[1][4].setHasAPiece(true);
player2Pieces[7].move(6,1);
    mySquare[1][6].setHasAPiece(true);

player2Pieces[8].move(1,2);
    mySquare[2][1].setHasAPiece(true);
player2Pieces[9].move(3,2);
    mySquare[2][3].setHasAPiece(true);
player2Pieces[10].move(5,2);
    mySquare[2][5].setHasAPiece(true);
player2Pieces[11].move(7,2);
    mySquare[2][7].setHasAPiece(true);


}

public void alternateSquares()    //assign every other to white
{
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row+=2)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 8; col+=2)
        {
            mySquare[row][col].setSquareColor("white");
        }          
    }    

    for(int row = 1; row < 8; row+=2)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col < 8; col+=2)
        {
            mySquare[row][col].setSquareColor("white");
        }          
    }       

}

public void initPieces(int whichPlayer)
{
  for(int p = 0; p <12; p++)
  {
      if(whichPlayer == 1)
          player1Pieces[p] = new Piece();
      else
          player2Pieces[p] = new Piece();
  }
}

public void printBoard()
{
System.out.print("     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7    \n");
System.out.print("---------------------------------------------------\n");
for(int row=0; row<8; row++)
    {
        System.out.print(row);
        for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(" | ");
            if(mySquare[row][col].getHasAPiece() == false)
                System.out.print("   ");   
            else if(mySquare[row][col].getHasARedPiece()==true)
                System.out.print(" R ");
            else if(mySquare[row][col].getHasARedPiece()==false)
                System.out.print(" * ");

        }
        System.out.print(" |\n");
        System.out.print("---------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
}

public void printPieces()
{
for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(player1Pieces[i].getX() + ", ");
        System.out.print(player1Pieces[i].getY());
        System.out.println();

    }  

}

public void printLegalMoves()
{
  Play p1 = new Play();
  CheckerMove[] temp = p1.getLegalMoves(1);

  for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++)
  {
      System.out.println("From: "+temp[i].fromX+", "+temp[i].fromY);
      System.out.println("To: "+temp[i].toX+", "+temp[i].toY);



  }
}


}//end class
```

main:

package neegjar;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class main 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Board newBoard = new Board();
    //newBoard.alternateSquares();
    //newBoard.alternateSquares();
        //System.out.println(newBoard.player1Pieces[0].getX());
    newBoard.placePieces();
    //newBoard.printBoard();
    newBoard.printLegalMoves();

    //newBoard.printPieces();



}
```

}//end class

Comment: I haven't read all your code, but your array goes from 0 to 7 and you are trying to access -1.  i.e. going off the edge of the board.  You need to add additional checks in to ensure a piece is not jumping off the board when you look for top left and top right.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic debugging question.

Your method canJump() has several places where it indexes an array with a number from which it subtracts 1 or 2; in one of these places, the result is -1, and there is no -1 index into your array (or any java array).

The error message tells you on exactly which line this occurs; I can't tell from your source, because the line numbers don't match what you have posted. It will be accurate on your source, however.

Learn to look at your java error messages. They are excellent sources of information about what the problem is (which is not universal of language runtimes). Its combination of a virtual machine and a strongly-typed language allows it to point you to the source of the problem much more exactly than some other languages.

And learn to use a debugger. You can step to the code where the problem is and see what values your variables have in the middle of execution. It is invaluable for discovering and fixing problems on your own.

Comment: It is customary, on StackOverflow, to upvote any answer you find useful (whether you asked the question or not), and to mark an answer that answers your question as "the answer". This increases people's reputation, which is all the coin anyone expects for all this reading and helping people with their problems. And answers to their own questions, of course.